# How to check if the user typed a symbol in java?

Tags: java, jsf

I am coming to this problem where I have a input field and inside my input field, I am checking if the user does not put any spaces and "@" symbol. However, I have wrote the code for checking for spaces, but having trouble to include the code for checking for "@" symbol. I tried using this: `&& value.contains("@")`, and change the `Object value` to `String value`, still did not work. Can any one show me how to check for "@" symbol prior to my code below. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
            public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        //Checking  if the user has typed only blank spaces and  "@" symbol. 

        //&& value.contains("@")
        if (value.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            FacesMessage msg
                    = new FacesMessage("Invalid input provided",
                            "Enter a valid address without @ Symbol and Spaces.");
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I preffer 'positive' checking, i.e. 'white list' and not 'black list'

Comment: Shouldn't your and not Just be an or? Things cannot be empty and contain something at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

```
if (!value.toString().contains(" ") && !value.toString().contains("@"))
```

Comment: Should I change from `Object value` to `String value`, right?

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
if (!value.toString().matches(".*[ @].*")) {
   // throw exception
```

Answer (score -1):

try this line :

```
 if(!value.toString().matches("[^a-z A-Z0-9]"))
```